# AngularJS with Router - memory increases continiously

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, memory, angular-ui-router

I have written an application with AngularJS v1.5.9 and using the router.
I started the Chrome task manager with shift + Esc - the process is Tab: WDM-VTA.
Than I startet the application in Chrome and took this snapshot:

[image: memory at start]

[image: snapshot at start]

Afterwards I clicked through the whole application (about 5 minutes) and took this snapshot:

[image: memory at end of measurement]

[image: snapshot at end of measurement]

The memory of Chrome increases a lot.
My question now would be how I can prevent this high increase of the memory?

Comment: Try garbage collection. On each page you leave clear your arrays and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what uses massiv memory, it is the breadcrump- framework:

```
angular-breadcrumb - v0.4.0-dev-2015-08-07
```

I used.
After I removed

```
<div data-ncy-breadcrumb></div>
```

from all my htmls, everything worked fine and memory went back after garbage collection where it has started.

Is there an adjustment of angular-breadcrumb to prevent memory consumtion?
It were the closure which increased a lot:

[image]